# Does PBFT violates the "f+1" round bound proved by Fischer M J and Lynch N A

Tags: distributed-system, consensus

Fischer M J and Lynch N A have proved the round bound needed by the Byzantine consensus in their paper [A lower bound for the time to assure interactive consistency](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a105946.pdf).
In short, they claimed that the lower bound for the rounds to reach Byzantine consensus is f+1, where f is the number of tolerant processes.

However, in the paper [Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance](http://pmg.csail.mit.edu/papers/osdi99.pdf), Byzantine consensus is reached by three rounds, namely pre-prepare, prepare, and commit.

Does PBFT violate the f+1 round bound?

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction; PBFT needs to account for the possibility of faulty leaders. In particular, we can always imagine an execution where the first f leaders we cycle through are all faulty. If the leader of an "epoch/view" is faulty, then consensus won't be reached.

(Note that the lower-bound is a "worst case'' bound -- a deterministic protocol must always have a worst-case execution of f+1 rounds, even if ''most'' executions are short.)

So in that sense f+1 bound is not a particularly strong limitation. It only says that there always exists some execution that might take f+1 rounds. With randomized protocols, we can often achieve consensus in an expected constant number of rounds (even though in the worst case, with very small probability, we may need f+1 rounds).